# Encountering missing client_id error while performing connection/refresh using unificationengine

Tags: unificationengine

While trying to perform connection/refresh for a facebook connection created using unification engine I am encountering the below error:

```
{"Status":{"facebook_111XXXXX":{"status":502,"info":"Missing client_id parameter."}}}
```

Here, The original connection id is replaced with facebook_111XXXXX for obvious reasons.

The payload I am passing is `{"uri":"unified://facebook_111XXXXX"}` to `https://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/connection/refresh`

Please advise what I am doing wrong here. Appreciate your help in advance!

Thanks & Best Regards,

A.P

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the client id and secret of facebook app, when the connector is added to your app in unificationengine developer portal.